# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Home\ClientLogoController::EditClientImage() Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 9 and I am getting this error I tried various methods to fix this issue but I'm stuck on this . Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
@php($i=1)
@foreach($client_image as $item)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
        <td>
            <img style="width:60px;height:50px;" src="{{ asset($item->client_logo_images) }}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('edit.client.logoimage',$item->id) }}">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
            </a> 
            <a class="btn btn-danger sm" href="">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I have passed Id with the route and capture. Here is the code. :-

```
Route::get('/edit/client/image/{id}','EditClientImage')->name('edit.client.logoimage');
```

And this is my controller code .

```
public function EditClientImage($id) {
    $client_logo=ClientLogoImage::findOrFail($id);
    return view('admin.home.edit_client',compact('client_logo'));
}
```

and an error is showing in line 51. This is my line 51. `public function EditClientImage($id)`
and I am redirecting it to edit_client Here is the code for edit_client

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('update.client.image') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
    @csrf
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $client_logo->id }}"  >
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Edit Profile</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="formFile" class="form-label mt-0">Profile Image Upload</label>
                <input name="client_image" id="image" class="form-control" type="file" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
    </div>
    
</form>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="{{ route('edit.client.logoimage', ['id' => $item->id]) }}">
```

You need to name it as id...

Comment: getting same error.

Comment: Worked Thank You I  performed cofig:cache and worked

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the way you are using name routing:

1. if you are using routed names you need to pass the parameter the same as the route:

```
Route::get('/edit/client/image/{id}','EditClientImage')>name('edit.client.logoimage');
```

in this, you have the `id` parameter and your link have to be as:

```
<a href="{{ route('edit.client.logoimage', ['id' => $item->id]) }}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
</a>
```

the other way you can use is just use the URL:

```
<a href="{{ url('/edit/client/image/' . $item->id) }}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
</a>
```